# Angular2 map and subscribe

Tags: json, angular, http, rxjs

I am developing an angular4 application. 
My Component.ts looks like:

```
ngOnInit() {

this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/data/').subscribe(data => this.temp = data);
// this.temp1 = JSON.parse(this.temp)
console.log(this.temp)

}
```

On the console I am getting 'undefined' for **this.temp**

Comment: add import statement for `Response` and typecast inside the `map`

Comment: So you're actually using Angular 4, not Angular 2. Since you seem to be just starting, forget about Http. It's deprecated in Angular 5. Use HttpClient. https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Thanks you, I am using HttpClient. Now I am not getting that error. But I am getting - Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: And I on the component side i am getting undefined value. Component code - `this.service.getAll().subscribe(data =>this.ReceivedJsonData=data);console.log(this.ReceivedJsonData);`

Comment: @naik3 edit your question, and post the relevant code, data, errors.

Comment: With the new `http` service you don't need to call `json()` any more. It's decoded automatically, see https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response

Comment: I have edited my question. And i have removed .json(), since its not available in httpClient()

Comment: I don't see how you could get the error you posted with the code you posted. But again. You don't need any map(). Read the guide. Carefully. You also need to realize that http is asynchronous (hence the use of observables): you can't possibly have anything inside this.ReceivedJsonData immediately after you've sent the request.

Comment: Sorry. I have changed my question. Now I am calling **http.get** in my component only. I am getting Undefined.

Comment: OK. Read my previous comment. Print the value **inside of the callback function passed to subscribe()**. HTTP is asynchronous. So the callback function is execute later, when the response comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your console.log like this

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/data/').subscribe(data => {this.temp = data; console.log(this.temp)});
```

Comment: Thanks @user2935953.